# NHibernate, Caching and custom SQL queries

Tags: nhibernate

We're using NHibernate with Memcache as the second level cache. Occasionally there is a need for more advanced queries or bulk query operations. From the book Nhibernate in Action they recommend the following:

*"It’s our view that ORM isn’t suitable for mass-update (or mass-delete) operations. If
you have a use case like this, a different strategy is almost always better: call a stored
procedure in the database, or use direct SQL UPDATE and DELETE statements for that
particular use case."*

My concern is that queries against the underlying database do not reflect in the cache (at least until cache expiry) and I was wondering if anyone has come up with any effective strategies for mixing and matching NHibernate with custom SQL statements?

Is there any way of getting say a bulk Update statement (executed with custom sql) to reflect in the second level cache? I am aware of being able to manually evict, but this removes the items from cache and thefore increases hits on the database.

Does the community have any solutions that have been found to be effective in dealing with this problem?

Comment: the community would also appreciate accepted answers....

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no method to keep the 2nd level cache up to date with massupdates. But you can partially evict the cache as described in: http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-sessioncache.